# How can I trigger non-blocking errors in Symfony2 forms?

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm developing a site with a large number of forms. So far, I've been able to handle most validation scenarios with property and constraint validations in `validation.yml`.

One requirement I have is to implement non-blocking errors. That is to say, a field generates a warning rather than a hard-stop error.

I've been able to work around the problem with flash messages, but these are quickly lost by users. Ideally there would be a field-level message I could inject similar to `ExecutionContextInterface::addViolationAt(...)`.

Comment: if this error not stop validation, form will be valid and succesfully submited. Mb you could validate entity by hand and show errors somethere? check this examle http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce 2 different [**validation groups**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) for your form.

One for the "real" validation and another one for the warnings.

You can also manually add errors in your controller:

```
$form->get('form-field')->addError(new FormError('field error message'));
```

or global errors:

```
 $form->addError(new FormError('form error message'));
```